# CSS background-image not showing on Mobile browsers

Tags: html, css, mobile, background

Im am working on a site that has to be fully responsive. if I resize down the window of my chrome browser, everything seems to be ok. but when trying it on a real mobile browser, everything is awful, my css images don't even show up. 
Thanks!
oh, the site is here: [www.interiorama.mx](http://interiorama.mx)

Comment: Which real mobile browser? Which CSS images? Your site contains no visible images even on desktop, as far as I can tell.

Comment: I can see them now both mobile and on desktop now that you changed the CSS file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your [css file](http://interiorama.mx/wp-content/themes/vantage-child/style.css?ver=1.4.2) is looking for the images on localhost: on line 148 and 166

```
url(http://localhost:8888/eli/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/Woods-Silla-Cafe-01.jpg)
```

Try changing that to your server's location: http://interiorama.mx/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/Pisos-Creativos-8.jpg and http://interiorama.mx/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/Woods-Silla-Cafe-01.jpg.